# Bypass Cloudflare cache when scraping a sitemap

Tags: web-scraping, cloudflare

I'm working on a web scrapper which uses the sitemap of a website in order to extract it's content. The problem I just faced is with the Cloudflare cache. I noticed that I'm receiving an old sitemap when I try to fetch the sitemap url. Of course I tryed with an incognito tab and recieved again an old sitemap version. Then I switched my internet to my mobile phone hotspot in order to check the behaviour with different IP and this way the sitemap was fresh, so I concluded it is some kind of IP level cache. I also noticed that when I add some query parameter to the sitemap url I receive a fresh sitemap version without the need to use different IP. The query param solution works fine for now, but I'm not sure if it is something I can rely on. I'm not so familiar with the cloudflare cache services and the best ways I can get arround them, so will be thankful if somebody helps me find a good and reliable solutions of the problem.